# TCP/IP socket on heroku

Tags: python, sockets, heroku

I created a TCP socket listening program in python. which I am trying to execute on Heroku.

Procfile:
`worker: python server.py jobs:work`

Server.py:

```
def start_server():

    server_config = config['Server']

    # configurations
    HOST = server_config['HOST']
    PORT = int(environ.get('PORT')) #server_config.getint('PORT')
    BUFFER_SIZE = server_config.getint('BUFFER_SIZE')

    # server socket setup
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(server_config.getint('LIMIT'))

    logging.info('server started %s:%d', HOST, PORT)
```

CLI:

```
F:\dev\>heroku run python server.py
Running python server.py on syswow64server... up, run.3213 (Free)
INFO:root:server started 0.0.0.0:14150
```

I know heroku use internal port mapping mesh so internal 14150 port doesn't map to external 14150 port. So how can I send request to my server? which port?

I tried sending request on port 80 and 443, but seems like they aren't mapped to 14150.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Procfile should look like this:

```
web: python server.py
```

After you deploy, run:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Your app will be available on port 80 externally (at the URL: your-app-name.herokuapp.com) that will be automatically routed for you to the port:

```
os.environ.get('PORT')
```

you're listening on internally.

The trick is 80 is routed to internal web process types, but not to worker process types.